# Issues installing a Rails app using Mysql on a linux server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, web-hosting

I have been following the support guide on [Host Gator](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails) 
I am on step 5.

Here is the first issue I get in terminal:

```
user@domain.com [~/rails_apps/app_name]# bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Using rake (0.8.3) 
Using RedCloth (4.2.9) 
Using coderay (0.9.8) 
Using hoe (3.13.1) 
Using i18n (0.4.2) 
Using minitest (1.7.2) 
Installing mysql (2.9.1) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /home3/user/ruby/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home3/user/ruby/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing mysql (2.9.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then try to use 'gem install mysql -v '2.9.1':

```
user@domain.com [~/rails_apps/app_name]# gem install mysql -v '2.9.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /home3/user/ruby/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home3/user/ruby/gems/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I have tried changing the permission of the folder by using:

```
chown root:root user/bin/sudo
```

without any luck.

Is this something that I will need to get help from Host Gator for?

Comment: Replace `gem 'mysql'`  with `gem 'mysql2'` in your gem file and then `bundle install` it will work for you I guess

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Linux, you need to install mysql development libraries/headers to compile the native extension against:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Depending on linux version, you might need to install other development libraries. Whether the error message says smth like:

> checking for mysql.h... no

it’s a sign that your box lacks a respective developer libraries/headers (`mysql` in this particular case.)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using two approaches -

Approach 1 : You need to install mysql dependencies in your system first -
if you are using linux, please install

`sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxslt`

and if you are using mac, please install

`brew install libxml2 libxslt`

Approach 2 : Or you can simply copied the missing files: mysql.h and other missing files to /usr/local/include/ and it went through the bundle install without a hitch.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! However I am still having issues, I first had to install brew, then I tried 'sudo apt-get install libxm12 libxslt' and got another error 'effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?' , terminal also told me I may need to 'brew install gcc'. But if i try to run that command line the system spits out '==> Installing dependencies for gcc: gmp, mpfr, libmpc, isl, cloog ==> Installing gcc dependency: gmp'. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @FroyT Please go through Approach 2, if you were not succeed through Approach 1. In Approach 2, You have to follow below steps -

Comment: Step 1 : $ cd /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/include/mysql  Step 2: $ cp mysql.h /usr/local/include/ Similarly, you will copy all missing files to /usr/local/include folder Step 3: then try bundle install. and Let me know, if you face any problem there.